# generating tag file dynamically in hybris

Tags: jquery, ajax, sap-commerce-cloud

Is it possible to append tag file in response from ajax . I am adding products to compare panel and the data required is name and thumbnail image. For getting the thumbnail image I have to use productPrimaryImage.tag
        img src cannot be used directly because of coding standards. I am fetching ProductData in Controller and sending the dynamically created div's via ajax

```
 //In my controller

innerdiv.append("<div id=\"innerdiv" + p.getCode() + "\" class=\"mandatory\">" + p.getName()+ "<product:productPrimaryImage product=\"${" + p + "}\" format=\"thumbnail\"/></div>");
```

But the tag does not render on page . I get a response like this which I am appending to a div :

```
<product:productPrimaryImage product="${de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data.ProductData@1164141b}" format="thumbnail"/>
```

Can you please let me know if this is possible or is there any other way to do it. I cannot use img src tag due to code review standards.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you render you compare panel.

Using Jquery you can clone the existing product image(div/source) to your panel when the user clicks the checkbox of the product, also store the respective data in cookies so that you can render the same compare panel on page refresh/load.

If you want to make ajax call to render the compare panel view, you can simply return JSP view in response and inject the same in your container. Here in JSP, you can use any tag you want to use.

Comment: Hello , I am not facing this issue on page load as my controller is rendering the panel. The problem occurs on ajax call itself.

Comment: in ajax call return JSP which only contain your panel view, then inject that view in the current container.

Comment: Hi I tried injecting jsp using this $('#compare-pane').load("WEB-INF/views/responsive/cms/productcomparecomponent.jsp");

However I get a 404 error . The URL formed is  this

https://localhost:9002/fras_retail_shop/Communication/Mobile-Phones/c/WEB-INF/views/responsive/cms/productcomparecomponent.jsp

Comment: No, that is not the correct way to do. Call your controller using ajax call, inside your controller return this JSP(you can feed the data to JSP using `model.setAtt..`), Now in the ajax response, you will get the HTML code which you can inject like `$('#compare-pane').html(responseData)`

Comment: In my code there are two different controllers .  First one is ProductCompareComponentController in which I am setting data using model.setAttribute .  This works fine on page load.

Second is DefaultPageController which is has ajax method inside it .This is triggered when user clicks on Add to compare checkbox .Here I am storing productcodes selected by user in cookie and returning the name,thumbnail image . Do you mean we need to use model.setAttribute inside this method also ?

Comment: `Here I am storing productcodes selected by user in cookie and returning the name,thumbnail image` How? , my point is, here you need to return the view of the panel(JSP), which you will get as HTML in ajax response, then you can inject/replace your current panel DIV with response HTML.

Comment: I am creating a html  like this :-  innerdiv.append("<div id=\"innerdiv" + p.getCode() + "\" class=\"mandatory\">" + p.getName()
+ "<product:productPrimaryImage product=\"${" + p + "}\" format=\"thumbnail\"/><button id=\"close" + p.getCode()
      + "\" class=\"compareButton\" type=\"submit\" data-product-id=\"" + p.getCode()
      + "\" onclick=\"closeCompareProductPanel(" + p.getCode() + ");\">Close X</button></div>");

But the problem here is tag does not render this way.

Yes I am replacing my inner div contents. But the thumbnail image comes only on page refresh

Comment: thanks . I will. Should I send a mail on contact@helphybris.com ?  Is this your email id ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174001/discussion-between-hybrisfreelance-and-aditi).